# Performance of Realm transactions vs SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, transactions, benchmarking, realm

I'm trying to compare the performance of Realm vs SQLite for a toy example. This is my test class:

```
public class Folder extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Index
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int numMessages;
    private int numRead;

    ...

}
```

I've coded equivalent Realm and SQLite DAOs. All the writes are made inside transactions in both cases. There are no indexes in SQLite other than the PK.

I've run a small informal benchmark  (N=10000), with exactly the same input data and in the same order for each persistence mechanism. I've found that:

1. Batch writes are about the same order, sometimes up to 2x faster in Realm, but sometimes a bit slower.
2. Deleting and updating one by one (by id) is 6x slower in Realm. Takes about 7 minutes to update one by one an array of 10k elements, while SQLite takes 1 minute.
3. Querying by id is 6x faster in Realm, but when sorting by name it is 1.6x slower.

I'm not really concerned about #1 since this is not a proper benchmark, and times varied a lot from one iteration to the next.

But #2 really surprised me, because times were actually consistent across iterations. Each individual update or delete was done inside a transaction (I usually would batch them in the real thing). This is how I write an instance:

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {

    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(<some folder>);
    }
});
```

And this is how I delete by id:

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {

    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        realm.where(Folder.class).equalTo("id", <some id>).findAll().clear();
    }
});
```

**What could be causing the slowdown? Is it the transaction body or the transaction overhead?**

About #3 I'm also puzzled about the slightly worse performance when sorting the results.
This is how I fetch by id:

```
Folder result = realm.where(Folder.class).equalTo("id", <some id>).findFirst();
```

And this is how I fetch everything sorted:

```
RealmResults<Folder> results = realm.where(Folder.class).findAllSorted("name");
```

Is the sorting that expensive?

---

UPDATE:

This is the top-10 table taken from tracedump when updating elements one by one by id (showing inclusive times)

```
    Method                                  Incl Cpu Time%
    ======================================================
    Real.copyToRealmOrUpdate                92.1%
    Realm.copyOrUpdate                      88.7%
    DefaultRealmModuleMediator.copyOrUpdate 85.3%
    FolderRealmProxy.copyOrUpdate           83.5%
    FolderRealmProxy.copyOrUpdate           80.1%
    Realm.createObject                      48.1%
    Table.addEmptyRowWithPrimaryKey         31.4%
    UncheckedRow.setLong                    17.6%
    Table.getUncheckedRow                   17.1%
    UncheckedRow.getByRowIndex              16.4%
```

Comment: The Realm code looks fairly much how I would expect, but it is hard to comment on the speed difference when you didn't post how you measure the speed + the same SQLite code.

Comment: Note that `executeTransaction(...)` is just equivalent to `realm.beginTransaction(); doWork(); realm.commitTransaction()` except it automatically handles errors, so using the transaction block shouldn't cause any measurable difference.

Comment: Wait, so to handle the error I have to do the manual transaction? But [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/Realm.java) in line 1117 it throws the exception, so I should be able to catch.

Comment: Yes, but it also calls `cancelTransaction` before throwing. That way you avoid accidentally having an open transaction if the exception is caught further out.

Comment: I've profiled the app when updating existing elements by id. Takes about 7 minutes for an array of 10000 elements. Looks like the transaction is cheap and most of the time is spent inside the copyToRealmOrUpdate method.

Comment: Yes, but that is expected. `copyToRealmOrUpdate` is doing the actual work of setting data. `commitTransaction` is just saving it.